# Total Accesses Increasing very Fast - Apache mod_status

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, apache-traffic-server

I enabled the mod_status module on my Apache 2 installation with Extended Status On. However, when I kept checking the server status page, the Total Access is increasing in a weird way(like 100 every 1 second) although i don't have any traffic going on the server and in the same time the server-status is not showing any requests in the requests listing below. How can I log any http access and see where the traffic is coming from and to what.

[image]

Comment: *"like 100 every 1 second*" doesn't quite match with the average 4.87 requests/sec that apache registers in your screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /var/log/apache2/access.log

stores http access.